# How can i convert checkboxes into dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have few checkboxes and I want to convert them into dropdown list. I tried something but don't know at the end what to do?

```
<form id="form-wysija-2" class="widget_wysija" action="#wysija" method="post">
    <p class="wysija-checkbox-label">Select list(s):</p>
        <p class="wysija-checkbox-paragraph">
            <label>
                <input class="wysija-checkbox validate[required]" type="checkbox" value="1" name="wysija[user_list][list_id][]">

                    General Antiques

            </label>
        </p>
        <p class="wysija-checkbox-paragraph">
            <label>
                <input class="wysija-checkbox validate[required]" type="checkbox" value="3" name="wysija[user_list][list_id][]">

                Antique & Collectible Tools

            </label>
        </p>
</form>
```

and i tried following jQuery to convert these checkboxes into dropdown list. but don't getting to how to done this successfully.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  var extra, checkBoxesName,
      checkBoxlabel,
      checkBoxes = $('.wysija-checkbox-paragraph');

  var checkBoxesLabel = $('.wysija-checkbox-label');


  checkBoxesName = checkBoxes.find('input').prop('name');
  checkBoxlabel = checkBoxes.find('label').text();

  checkBoxesLabel.append('<select name="'+checkBoxesName+'">'+extra+'</select>');
  $('.wysija-checkbox-paragraph').each(function(n){
    var dataText = $(this).find('label').text();
    $('select[name='+checkBoxesName+']').append('<option value="'+n+'">'+dataText+'</option>');
  });

  //checkBoxes.remove();

});
```

Comment: do you have any fiddle for this?

Comment: WHat is expected output? All checkboxes in form collected into one select?

Comment: its messed up output... and let me try fiddle

Comment: Why not just change the HTML the application outputs/uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var checkBoxes = $('.wysija-checkbox-paragraph'),
    checkBoxesLabel = $('.wysija-checkbox-label'),
    checkBoxesName = checkBoxes.find('input').prop('name')
    $select = $('<select name="' + checkBoxesName + '"></select>').appendTo(checkBoxesLabel);

checkBoxes.each(function (n) {
    var dataText = $(this).find('label').text();
    var dataValue = $(this).find('input').val();
    $select.append('<option value="' + dataValue + '">' + dataText + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-wysija-2" class="widget_wysija" action="#wysija" method="post">
    <p class="wysija-checkbox-label">Select list(s):</p>
    <p class="wysija-checkbox-paragraph">
        <label>
            <input class="wysija-checkbox validate[required]" type="checkbox" value="1" name="wysija[user_list][list_id][]" /> General Antiques
        </label>
    </p>
    <p class="wysija-checkbox-paragraph">
        <label>
            <input class="wysija-checkbox validate[required]" type="checkbox" value="3" name="wysija[user_list][list_id][]" /> Antique & Collectible Tools
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Note, that since checkboxes allow to select multiple values, you might want to add `multiple` attribute to selectbox, in order to allow the same behavior.

Comment: @Chris Pietschmann I wanted to make it more reliable, but forgot. Thank you for improving it!

Answer (score -1):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  var extra, checkBoxesName,
      checkBoxlabel,
      checkBoxes = $('.wysija-checkbox-paragraph');

  var checkBoxesLabel = $('.wysija-checkbox-label');


  checkBoxesName = checkBoxes.find('input').prop('name');
  checkBoxlabel = checkBoxes.find('label').text();

  checkBoxesLabel.append('<select name="'+checkBoxesName+'">'+extra+'</select>');
  $('.wysija-checkbox-paragraph').each(function(n){

    var dataText = $(this).find('label').text();
    $('.wysija-checkbox-paragraph').append('<select name="'+checkBoxesName+']" > <option value="'+n+'">'+dataText+'</option></select>');
  });

  //checkBoxes.remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form-wysija-2" class="widget_wysija" action="#wysija" method="post">
    <p class="wysija-checkbox-label">Select list(s):</p>
        <p class="wysija-checkbox-paragraph">
            <label>
                <input class="wysija-checkbox validate[required]" type="checkbox" value="1" name="wysija[user_list][list_id][]">

                    General Antiques

            </label>
        </p>
        <p class="wysija-checkbox-paragraph">
            <label>
                <input class="wysija-checkbox validate[required]" type="checkbox" value="3" name="wysija[user_list][list_id][]">

                Antique & Collectible Tools

            </label>
        </p>
  
</form>
```